# For each item, add an item from another foreach

Tags: php, wordpress, foreach

I'm working on wordpress and I'm working with some `foreach`, here's my code:

```
$content = get_the_content();
if (preg_match_all('/<div id="description" class="description">([^<]*)<\/div>/', $content, $match)) {
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($match[0]); $i = $i + 1) {
        echo $match[0][$i];
    }
}

$attachments =& get_children($args);
if ($attachments) {
    foreach ($attachments as $attachment) {
        foreach ($attachment as $attachment_key => $attachment_value) {
            $imageID = $attachment->ID;
            $imageTitle = $attachment->post_title;
            $imagearray = wp_get_attachment_image_src($attachment_value, $size, false);
            $imageAlt = get_post_meta($imageID, '_wp_attachment_image_alt', true);
            $imageURI = $imagearray[0]; // 0 is the URI
            $imageWidth = $imagearray[1]; // 1 is the width
            $imageHeight = $imagearray[2]; // 2 is the height
            ?>
            <div class="col_1_2">
                <div id="attachment_<?php echo $imageID; ?>" class="wp-caption alignnone" style="width: 356px;">
                    <a rel="lightbox-0" href="<?php echo $imageURI; ?>"><img
                            class="wp-image-<?php echo $imageID; ?> size-full" title="<?php echo $imageTitle; ?>"
                            src="<?php echo $imageURI; ?>" alt="<?php echo $imageAlt; ?>" width="456" height="304"/></a>
                    <p class="wp-caption-text"><?php echo $imageTitle; ?>
                    <div class="link-veteran"></div>
                    <div class="popup"><?php echo $imageAlt; ?>
                        <div class="arrow-up"></div>
                    </div>
                    </p>
                    <p><?php echo $match[0][$i]; ?></p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <?php
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

I want that for the 1st attachment, the 1st description has to displayed with it. For the 2nd attachment, the 2nd description has to displayed with it, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does below code work for you ?

```
$content = get_the_content();
$j=0;               

                    if (preg_match_all('/<div id="description" class="description">([^<]*)<\/div>/', $content, $match)) {

                        for( $i = 0; $i < count($match[0]); $i = $i+1 ) {

                            echo $match[0][$i];

                        }
                    }       

                    $attachments =& get_children($args);
                        if ($attachments) {
                            foreach($attachments as $attachment) {
                                foreach($attachment as $attachment_key => $attachment_value) {
                                    $imageID = $attachment->ID;
                                    $imageTitle = $attachment->post_title;
                                    $imagearray = wp_get_attachment_image_src($attachment_value, $size, false);
                                    $imageAlt = get_post_meta($imageID, '_wp_attachment_image_alt', true);
                                    $imageURI = $imagearray[0]; // 0 is the URI
                                    $imageWidth = $imagearray[1]; // 1 is the width
                                    $imageHeight = $imagearray[2]; // 2 is the height
                            ?>

                            <div class="col_1_2">
                                <div id="attachment_<?php echo $imageID; ?>" class="wp-caption alignnone" style="width: 356px;">
                                    <a rel="lightbox-0"  href="<?php echo $imageURI;  ?>"><img class="wp-image-<?php echo $imageID; ?> size-full" title="<?php echo $imageTitle; ?>" src="<?php echo $imageURI; ?>" alt="<?php echo $imageAlt; ?>" width="456" height="304" /></a>
                                    <p class="wp-caption-text"><?php echo $imageTitle; ?><div class="link-veteran"></div><div class="popup"><?php echo $imageAlt; ?><div class="arrow-up"></div></div></p>
                                    <p><?php echo $match[0][$j]; ?></p>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                        <?php
                break;

                    }
                    $j++;
                }
            }
```

Comment: Ok I get it, you have to declare an empty variable. It works by the way ! Thanks